# electron app load faster in development then in production

Tags: performance, electron

When I creat an Electron app, it takes around 6 seconds to load with npm start but 30 if I run the exe installed from the installer

I used Electron forge to create the app and electron builder to build the exe, all my dependencies are the latest versions and the app the just what you get when you create an app with electron forge i didn't modify anything in it